# Ubuntu 20.04 "Show Applications" button is missing in the Ubuntu dock

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

The "show-show-apps-button" is on in the dconf editor, but the button is still missing in the dock.
However, there are "Applications" and "Places" on the upper left of my screen. I'm wondering if I can move them onto the ubuntu dock.

[image: current appearance]